# Treasure hunt 'round the world! (clue 5)

Tags: cipher

*If you're interested in starting the treasure hunt from the very beginning, check out the [prologue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16551/treasure-hunt-round-the-world)!*

---

After solving the monotonous and mindless puzzle (of *course* jet fuel can't melt steel beams), you're able to catch a few Z's before the next step of the treasure hunt. Lucky, too, since you hadn't slept for quite a few hours before this moment. You savor the sleep as best as you can before being abruptly awoken by, of all things, an air horn.

A man in a black suit with dark sunglasses stands above you, holding said air horn in one hand and an envelope with your name on it in the other. You begrudgingly take the envelope, glaring at the man. He, of course, remains expressionless. Opening the envelope, you find a letter, as well as a long, folded piece of parchment.

Better start with the letter, you figure.

> Dear ***[insert username here],***
>
> Congratulations on solving the previous, and final, interlude! Just a couple of clues to go before you arrive at the penultimate challenge - but that's not cause to cheer yet, friend. The puzzles don't get any easier from here. I'm sure you've already noted the parchment in the envelope with this letter. That parchment has your next puzzle on it. But you already knew that! Get cracking! But more importantly, have fun!
>
> Yours truly,
>
> Bailey M
> Puzzlemaster for the Treasure Hunt 'Round the World

You scoff. Surely by this point the puzzlemaster knows you're ready for any puzzle. Unfolding the parchment, you read:

> <sub>aVZCT1J3MEtHZ29BQUFBTlNVaEVVZ0FBQWZRQUFBSDBFQUFBQUFDK0xWd1ZBQUFIV2tsRVFWUjQy
> dTNkTVc0VFVSQ0E0VjFrTEZGUklabzBRTVFORUp3QmhJVEVDVGdHTlJKOUtncXVrVnlBTmtjZ3Br
> dUZoS2hKWVc3Z0lDYmptYmY3ZlgzV3ordjNzMHN4ZXZOK1B3RUxkODh0QUtFRFFnZUVEZ2dkRURv
> Z2RFRG9nTkJCNklEUUFhRURRZ2VFRGdnZEVEb2dkQkE2SUhSQTZJRFFBYUVEUWdlRURnZ2RoQTRJ
> SFJBNklIUkE2SURRQWFFRFFnZUVEa0lIaEE0SUhSQTZJSFJBNklEUUFhR0QwQUdoQTBJSGhBNElI
> UkE2SUhSQTZDQjBRT2lBMEFHaEEwSUhoQTRJSFJBNklIUllqMDNWQjI5UGJxNlhkalAzZXh2S0R1
> bTVRelkyVkJmelhMVkY4ajY1N2p2aDFSMkVEZ2dkRURvZ2RFRG9nTkFCb1FOQ0I2RURRZ2VFRGdn
> ZEtOWjBldTM5L1ErZis2MXEvKzd0NittN1RXT0hqTGREbW9iKzVOdWJWdzJYdFoyZVIvNzg4TkJt
> enl2blh0c084ZW9PQ0IwUU9pQjBFRG9nZEVEb2dOQUJvUU5DQjRRT0NCMkVEaXpXa0ljc3ZuaDVk
> WkZ6NWRPdmx4OXRpdkhaSVlzSS9lcmk5Nk9jSysrZVRvay80K0hUUXcrUGcwYUdSV09ubHZZY1Ux
> M21EdkhxRGdnZEVEb0lIUkE2SUhSQTZJRFFBYUVEUWdlRURnZ2RoQTRJSFJqSnhpMDRucnhSMDln
> b2FkNGdhbXhBRms5MFFPaUEwRUhvZ05BQm9RTkNCNFFPQ0IwUU9pQjBFRG9nZEVEb1FHZkdWSThv
> TXJSNWVKUTBjNGkxYXRWNG9nTkNCNFFPUWdlRURnZ2RFRG9nZEVEb2dOQUJvWVBRQWFFRFF4dHll
> dTMwMCs1aHpwV2ZmYkVsbHNBT1dVVG9sMmZUMllqcnJocmF2TzNLa1RIV3ZKTlkxN2hEdkxvRFFn
> ZUVEa0lIaEE0SUhSQTZJSFJBNklEUUFhRURRZ2VoQXd2U2RIcnR4Kzc4WjhObFBaaisyREoyeUln
> N1pLNDYwWEo3Y25POXRNMFhHd2VObklnYSt4V3JUbW85Zk9VMTdwRFZQZEc1MDMvTjU4ajJxenV3
> R2Y5SEI0UU9DQjJFRGdnZEVEb2dkRURvZ05BQm9RTkNCNkVEeTFVMzFQSjQrdVgyWTRjY3gxdzNP
> TGZDbTEwMHB0cDFlczNlVzhNVGZZVWlHN3RyRkZMMmYzUkE2SURRQWFFRFFnZUVEa0lIaEE0SUhS
> QTZJSFJBNklEUUFhSERXaFdPcWZZOGFUTjI5SEhYVmZmOFRtYnNQZEVCb1FOQ0I0UU9RZ2VFRGdn
> ZEVEb2dkRURvZ05BQm9ZUFFBYUVESTJ0N21tcHNTUEgvcjV6NTExV3JyaHVkN0RuVXU4WlRYajNS
> UWVpQTBBR2hBMElIaEE0SUhSQTZJSFFRT2lCMFFPaUEwQUdoQTNldmNFeDF6RkhCbm9PWHNWWGxq
> ZDVXRGZWMlhYWGRudmRFQjYvdWdOQUJvUU5DQjRRT0NCMFFPaUIwRURvZ2RFRG9nTkFCb1FOM2Ir
> NDZMQm9aOTh2NzI4eEJ3N3l4ek5pYWV3NWUxZzNtam5pM1BOSEJxenNnZEVEb2dOQUJvUU5DQjRR
> T0NCMkVEZ2dkRURvZ2RFRG9RSWJDMDFRamc0WjFJNTFWWTRpeDRkcXFUNjQ3bDdUbjd2SkVCNFFP
> Q0IwUU9nZ2RFRG9nZEVEb2dOQUJvUU5DQjRRT0NCMkVEZ2dkR0VyaHNjbFZrOHd4UFk4SnpweFdy
> NXNwSC9GdWRqMkczQk1kdkxvRFFnZUVEZ2dkRURvZ2RFRG9nTkJCNklEUUFhRURRZ2VFRHR5OXpS
> Sy9WT2FZWWQyNGFOYjl1RzFkZWF2T3ZKY2pqaE43b2dOQ0I0UU9RbmNMUU9pQTBBR2hBMElIaEE0
> SUhSQTZJSFFRT2lCMFlDeURqcWxXRFh6R0JnMTdqazVtcmpwdmFMTnU0TFBuS0xJbk9pQjBFRG9n
> ZEVEb2dOQUJvUU5DQjRRT0NCMkVEZ2dkRURvZ2RPRDRWbmlhNm1GMUk1MlJkY1UrTi9QMDJieDcz
> Zk1iMTQzUGVxS0RWM2UzQUlRT0NCMFFPaUIwUU9pQTBBR2hBMElIb1FOQ0I0UU9DQjA0dHJucldO
> MGliM2JhV0diZHJ4ajVUcG1yWHVLOTlrUUhoQTVDQjRRT0NCMFFPaUIwUU9pQTBBR2hBMElIb1FO
> Q0I0UU85RkoybXVyMjVPWjZhVGR6ekdIUjJMb2o1NUpHdnBQQlhFOTBRT2dnZEVEb2dOQUJvUU5D
> QjRRT0NCMFFPZ2dkRURvZ2RFRG9RTFZOejJXOXYvL2hjNzlWN2QrOWZUMTlEL3g5WUtRejcyOXZr
> M2N1YWVSdWRmM2txcnMxYU9oUHZyMTUxWEJaMittNVp3TmUzUUdoQTBJSGhBNElIUkE2Q0IwUU9p
> QjBRT2lBMEFHaEEwSUgvc0ZteEVXL2VIbDFrWFBsMDYrWEgyMEtoTjdDMWNYdlJ6bFgzajJkRWtQ
> dmVoRHdZVlVISTlmcHVpNnY3b0RRUWVpQTBBR2hBMElIaEE0SUhSQTZJSFJBNkNCMFFPaUEwSUZl
> Tm01QkY1SGh5THhSMHI2ZnZMNVZlNklEUWdlaEEwSUhoQTRJSFJBNklIUkE2SURRQWFHRDBBR2hB
> MElIZWpHbTJrYmU2T1J0NTdUMkhNdU0zWSs4czJuSEhISDFSQWV2N29EUUFhRURRZ2VFRGdnZEVE
> b2dkQkE2SUhSQTZJRFFnYU1iY25ydDlOUHVZYzZWbjMyeEpSQjZFNWRuMDluYWZxakkyR1ZzZExK
> cUxETjI1Y3l4WHEvdWdOQUJvUU5DQjRRT0NCMkVEZ2dkRURvZ2RFRG9nTkFCb1FQL29PbjAyby9k
> K2MrR3kzb3cvYkZsR05GY05aSzNQYm01WHRyTmpKMWFtdmRMeEU0ZTdicnFKZTRRcis2QTBBR2hn
> OUFCb1FOQ0I0UU9DQjBRT2lCMFFPaUEwRUhvd0lMVWphaytubjY1L1hBYzh4SlBqZ1M4dW9QUUFh
> RURRZ2VFRGdnZEVEb2dkRURvSUhSQTZJRFFBYUVEUWdlRURnZ2RFRG9nZEJBNklIUkE2SURRQWFF
> RFFnZUVEZ2dkaEE0SUhSQTZJSFJBNklEUUFhRURRZ2VoQTBJSGhBNElIUkE2SUhSQTZJRFFBYUdE
> MEFHaEEwSUhoQTRJSFJBNklIUkE2Q0IwUU9pQTBBR2hBMElIaEE0SUhSQTZDQjFZcnIvYXpWWGFK
> ZTZTcGdBQUFBQkpSVTVFcmtKZ2dnPT0=</sub>

Your eyes bug out of your head, but you take a moment and the letters, numbers, and symbols settle on the page. Turning the parchment over, you read:

> *9711599105105*
>
> *Good luck converting the previous assortment of characters into your next destination. If your fail at first, try converting again!*
>
> *- Bailey M*

---

*Where is your next destination?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decoding with base64 gives:

> `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`

Decoding AGAIN with base64 gives a png file:

> [image]

Scanning the QR code gives a link:

> http://q-r.to/baeoka

Those colors in order are

> 84/114/97 ; 118/101/108 ; 32/116/111; 32/84/97 ; 115/104/107; 101/110/116

And converting to ASCII gives the message

> **Travel to Tashkent**.

Comment: Too quick. Looks like you really were prepared for any puzzle! :) I guess the next one will have to be more wordplay... that is, after all, my forte.

Comment: @BaileyM: Yeah, re-encoding something over and over doesn't really make for a good puzzle IMO. I "solved" this one through recognition of common codes and online converters.

Comment: I really liked the idea of encoding a string as a hex codes in an image... I got a bit lost in translation after that, as you can see. Ah, well - you win some, you lose some!

Comment: @BaileyM: I actually remembered reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AACS_encryption_key_controversy) article a while back - I assume that was your inspiration?

Comment: Wow, actually no, not at all - I've never seen that before. Guess I'm not the only one with the idea!